# Bclogo skipping a page before a section

Tags: tikz-pgf, page-breaking, tikz-arrows, samepage

An alumni gave us a template for writing lessons. There was a "transition" environment already defined. There was a misalignment between the line and the arrow that I fixed, but whenever there is a section or subsection after the transition, it tends to skip a page, while it wouldn't do it without. The whole point of this environment is to precede a section, so that's a bummer.

Here's a MWE and the picture associated.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\transition}[1]{
\begin{samepage}
    \noindent \begin{bclogo}[barre = line, noborder = true, epBarre=2.0, logo=\ ]{} \vspace{0. em}\textit{#1} \end{bclogo}

\vspace*{-4.8 em}

\begin{flushleft}
    \hspace{0.38 em}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (a) {};
        \node (b) [below of=a] {};
        \draw[-latex, line width = .2em] (a) -- (b);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{flushleft}
\vspace*{-3.3 em}
\end{samepage}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]
Just a bit more text to be a relevant MWE. Just a bit more text to be a relevant MWE. Just a bit more text to be a relevant MWE. Just a bit more text to be a relevant MWE. Just a bit more text to be a relevant MWE. Just a bit more text to be a relevant MWE.
\transition{This is cut on two pages, while there is still a lot of space on the first one! I'm only writing a short transition between two parts but it stills skip a page. That is annoying.}

\section{Test}

\end{document}
```

[image: The "transition" environment skips a page.]

Would anyone have an idea concerning this issue? I have little knowledge about bclogos and the issue seems to be linked to the `samepage` command, but I don't know how to prevent that without having to put some ugly `\vspace*{}` before. Sometimes it's not even possible, see next picture.

[image: A really big gap, not fixable with vertical spaces.]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure about your problem, but I think that if there is not enough space to put some text after section title, the title jumps to next page.

Comment: In any case, your code doesn't work for me. It complains about `missing \begin{document}`. Did you forget some `package`?

Comment: It makes sense that the title jumps to the next page, but the arrow could keep on the same page though... Maybe a simple `pagebreak` would do the trick, but not so satisfying. Feels like taping a leaking faucet!

That's weird, I just relaunched it on TeXMaker, works fine with exactly the code I gave you. Works on Overleaf too: [https://www.overleaf.com/13665514chbpgjrxrjph].

Comment: When I compile your code, the section title goes to page 2 and so does the arrow with it. What should go to the next page exactly?

Comment: @cfr The arrow should keep on the first page, not be cut to follow the title. It's normal for the title to go to the second page but no reason for the arrow to do so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't actually know what `bclogo` does and I don't read French. So I'm guessing what might be required. Here's a pure Ti*k*Z version of `\transition`, which takes an optional command in case you want a heading to the transition text. `\mylogo` can be redefined to the logo you want.

The idea is that putting everything inside a single `tikzpicture` means it will always stay on the same page. It is a single box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,calc,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\newcommand\mylogo{\includegraphics[height=5mm]{cauldron}}% substitute whatever you want here
\newcommand{\transition}[2][]{%
  \medskip
  \par
  \noindent
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (a) [font=\itshape, align=justify, inner sep=0pt, text width=\linewidth-\parindent] {#2};
    \draw [line width=.2em, -Latex] (a.north west) ++(-.75\parindent,0) coordinate (b) -- (a.south -| b);
    \node (c) [anchor=south] at (b) {\mylogo};
    \node [anchor=west, inner xsep=0pt, font=\sffamily\bfseries] at (c.center -| a.west) {#1};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]
Just a bit more text to be a relevant MWE. 
Just a bit more text to be a relevant MWE. 
Just a bit more text to be a relevant MWE. 
Just a bit more text to be a relevant MWE. 
Just a bit more text to be a relevant MWE. 
Just a bit more text to be a relevant MWE. 
Just a bit more text to be a relevant MWE. 
Just a bit more text to be a relevant MWE. 
Just a bit more text to be a relevant MWE.
\transition[Optional Title]{This is cut on two pages, while there is still a lot of space on the first one! I'm only writing a short transition between two parts but it stills skip a page. That is annoying.}

\section{Test}

\end{document}
```

[image: transitional cauldron]